# Apply transparency to a raster layer by using actions

Tags: qgis, python, style, actions

i have a specific action to load an raster layer by clicking on it, however i need to know if is possible to open that specific file and automatically apply a style.

My idea is when someone click and open that raster file, automatically he applies a transparency of 50%. Beeing "raster_path" an attribute field with URL directory.

I have the present code in Action (python):

```
import os pathin='[% "raster_path" %]'
layerID = str(os.path.splitext(os.path.split(pathin)[1])[0]) qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(pathin,layerID)
```

i tried, with diferent results, saving a .qml file and apply to it, however for diferent raster show very diferent results with very bad resolution.

Is there a way to apply a transparency of 0.5 (50%) directly on the code above or do i need to set and field with .qml URL and load somehow on the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hammering a little bit more, i got it using the following:

```py
import os
pathin='[% "ABRIR_SEC" %]'
layerID = str(os.path.splitext(os.path.split(pathin)[1])[0])
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(pathin,layerID)
rlayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
rlayer.renderer().setOpacity(0.5) #set the value you need as default
rlayer.triggerRepaint()
```